# Save a file in a folder using file_put_contents PHP

Tags: php, file

I have a simple PHP that will save a file to a specific folder. I already change the permission in 777 but I'm getting errors:

```
Warning: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/foldername/): failed to open stream: Is a directory on line 22
Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted on line 23
```

How to fix these?

PHP

```
$file_name = '';
$file_binary = '';

$folder = "foldername";
$file_name = isset($_POST['file_name']) ? $_POST['file_name'] : '';
$file_binary = isset($_POST['file']) ? $_POST['file'] : '';
$file_directory = "/var/www/html/foldername/".$file_name;
file_put_contents($file_directory,str_replace("\\","",$file_binary));
chmod($file_directory,0777);
```

Comment: Are you sure, `"/path/foldername/".$file_name` is a valid path ? Never set permission to 777, 644 will be sufficient for files and 755 for folders.

Comment: @Gaurav, i already change the file path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1):

When there is a fileupload, you should get the data with $_FILE, not with $_POST. Try to change your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are few correction need to be done in your code. first please add a default file name into your ternary operator, and instead of using `file_put_content` use `fopen` along with `'r+'` please check the [url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for more options, and before creting a file need to check directory exist and is writable. Hope this will help you.

Comment: the directory is writable, i double checked the folder permission.

Comment: check through the code it may be happen sometime like php user is different and we are checking from another user.

Comment: i already use the fopen, but still i'm getting same error in `file_put_contents`

Comment: Have you use both fopen and file_put_content at the same time, I saw your error message it looks like file name is missing in as parameter "Warning: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/foldername/):".

Comment: no i didn't use both at the same time, i comment the `file_put_contents`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$file_name = '';
$file_binary = '';

$folder = "foldername";
$file_name = isset($_POST['file_name']) ? $_POST['file_name'] : '';
$file_binary = isset($_POST['file']) ? $_POST['file'] : '';
//to create directory:

$folderPath = "/var/www/html/foldername";

is_dir($folderPath) || @mkdir($folderPath) || die("Can't Create folder");

$file_directory = "/var/www/html/foldername/".$file_name;
file_put_contents($file_directory,str_replace("\\","",$file_binary));
chmod($file_directory,0777);
```

Comment: please check if $file_name is null

Comment: i tried to echo the `$file_name` and i get a blank only

Comment: try to use $_FILE

Comment: do you get anything from this ?

print_r($_FILES);